# how to set many targets to ProxyFactoryBean?

Tags: java, interceptor, spring-aop, spring-4, aspect

I am working with Spring 4 AOP and right now, i have my ProxyFactoryBean configured like this:

```
@Bean
@Primary
public ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean() {
    ProxyFactoryBean proxyFactoryBean = new ProxyFactoryBean();
    proxyFactoryBean.setTarget(new ClientService());
    proxyFactoryBean.addAdvice(new LoggingAdvice());
    proxyFactoryBean.addAdvice(new DebugInterceptor());
    return proxyFactoryBean;
}
```

This works, but the target is just the ClientService object.

Is it possible to set many targets and not just one ? I want to set those advices to an entire package, if it is possible. Otherwise, set specifics targets, but again, not just one. How could you do that ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxying all beans in an application context that match certain criteria is easiest done with Spring's [AutoProxy-Facility](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-autoproxy). Alas, the pointcut api is somewhat cumbersome to use in java based config; I usually subclass the [AbstractAutoProxyCreator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/framework/autoproxy/AbstractAutoProxyCreator.html) so I can express the pointcut in java code.

For instance, I'd do something like:

```
@Bean
AbstractAutoProxyCreator autoProxyCreator() {
    return new AbstractAutoProxyCreator() {
        @Override 
        protected Object[] getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(Class<?> beanClass, String beanName, TargetSource customTargetSource) {
            if (BusinessService.class.isAssignableFrom(beanClass)) {
                return new Object[] {loggingAdvice()};
            } else {
                return DO_NOT_PROXY;
            }
        }
    };
}

@Bean
LoggingAdvice loggingAdvice() {
    return new LoggingAdvice();
}

@Bean
public PersonService personService() {
    return new PersonService();
}
```

This code is untested, as I don't have an IDE with Spring (or Maven) at hand, but the gist should work.

Comment: @jscherman; hi, can you share your code?

Comment: hey @fatemeakbari, it's been 6 years since I posted this I don't have the code anymore, sorry

Comment: thanks @jscherman, my problem solved

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to achieve can be done by using point-cuts in an aspect oriented language. So you can define point cut to automatically apply the aspect to multiple targets say implementing the same interface. See more details [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) (scroll to 9.2.3 Declaring a point cut).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is with using AspectJ annotations - use within() expression

For this you will need to

1. Create "Aspect" Class using @Component and @Aspect annotations
2. Create "Pointcut" definition within the aspect using @Pointcut annotation, 
   example is mentioned below
3. Create "Advice" - Around,Before,AfterThrowing,AfterReturning and provide 
   appropriate advice implementation
4. Enable AspectJ configuration using @EnableAspectJAutoProxy on your 
   configuration class with 'proxyTargetClass=true' if you want to use CGLIB proxy
5. and make sure your aspect class is on the scan path

e.g.

```
@Pointcut(within(*..*Service))
public void allService(){}
```

above within() expression will match all classes ending with 'Service', you can also match all classes in a particular package as well.